# PHP fsockopen() works once but fails on subsequent tries

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm trying to poll a server at intervals using a PHP socket connection. However, when I run the script I get the correct behaviour the first time, but then the second time I get the following error:

```
fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

When I run the script a third time I get the following error:

```
fsockopen(): unable to connect to :0 (Failed to parse address "")
```

That error repeats every subsequent attempt.
However, if I wait about a minute and retry then everything works. It seems to me like I'm having a problem with the socket connection not closing and then being refused when I try to create it again.

The class that handles the socket communication is:

```
class FsSocket
{   
private $password = "XXXXXXXXXX";
private $port = "8030";
private $host = "hostname";

function event_socket_create( $host=null, $port=null, $password=null ) {
    if ( $host == null ) {
        $host = $this->host;
    }
    if ( $port == null ) {
        $port = $this->port;
    }
    if ( $password == null ) {
        $password = $this->password;
    }

    error_log( $host.":".$port );
    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errdesc, 2) or die("Connection to $host failed");
    socket_set_blocking($fp,false);

    if ($fp) {
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $buffer = fgets($fp, 1024);
            usleep(100); //allow time for reponse
            if (trim($buffer) == "Content-Type: auth/request") {
            fputs($fp, "auth $password\n\n");
            break;
            }
        }
        return $fp;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }           
}


function event_socket_request($fp, $cmd) {

    if ($fp) {    
        fputs($fp, $cmd."\n\n");    
        usleep(100); //allow time for reponse

        $response = "";
        $i = 0;
        $contentlength = 0;
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $buffer = fgets($fp, 4096);
            if ($contentlength > 0) {
            $response .= $buffer;
            }

            if ($contentlength == 0) { //if contentlenght is already don't process again
                if (strlen(trim($buffer)) > 0) { //run only if buffer has content
                    $temparray = explode(":", trim($buffer));
                    if ($temparray[0] == "Content-Length") {
                        $contentlength = trim($temparray[1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            usleep(100); //allow time for reponse

            //optional because of script timeout //don't let while loop become endless
            if ($i > 10000) { break; } 

            if ($contentlength > 0) { //is contentlength set
                //stop reading if all content has been read.
                if (strlen($response) >= $contentlength) {  
                break;
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return $response;
    }
    else {
    echo "no handle";
    }
}
}
```

The code that calls the socket class is as follows:

```
$socket = new FsSocket();
$fp = $socket->event_socket_create();

$cmd = "sofia_contact $to->user@$to->domain";
$response = $socket->event_socket_request($fp, $cmd);

fclose($fp);
unset($socket);
```

I haven't implemented the loop bit yet. I'm trying to get this working by manually refreshing the page first.

Comment: first of all don't paste passwords here.

Comment: @alpera That's a handy dandy piece of advice if ever I saw one. +1

Comment: unset($socket) is NOT a good thing to do. You should call a destructor  first. Unset a class instance without destruct runs into resource problems after many calls.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on passwords. However this is just sample code that I copied directly from the FreeSwitch wiki, so this is not any kind of production or even testing password. Also, the unset($socket) bit was a guess on my part to try and see some change in behaviour - anything would be better than the same thing!

Comment: Looks like a firewall issue to me. Try disabling it.

Comment: Firewall is completely open on our test box.

Comment: I'm seeing 11 years of moans about this issue https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=11058 so you should try server configuration/apache tinkering start/stop. Usually if the script runs once it should run all the time.